# Latex for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, latex

Does anyone know of a latex distribution/front end they highly recommend for OS X?

If the front end had some features you recommend, what are they and why?

Thanks!

Comment: There is in fact a LaTeX stackexchange site, and there's a similar question there: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx You could post a new question there, if you feel the answers on that question aren't sufficient. Going to go ahead and vote to close as off-topic, since there's such a good other forum.

Comment: Thanks for the info Jefromi! Next time I'll be sure use that forum instead.

Comment: @Jefromi: For future reference, the [existence of the latex stack exchange site does **not** render latex questions off topic here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63211/are-questions-appropriate-for-specific-se-sites-off-topic-in-so). This particular question does not belong because it is a "what software" question that should go to *Super User* or--of course--TeX, LaTeX and Friends.

Comment: @dmckee: Okay, thanks. I assumed that because there was an unclosed question there that looked like it pretty much answered this one, that was the place for it. (Though that meta question is far from definitive, from my reading.) And for what it's worth, prior to the existence of the new stackexchange site, I would've voted to migrate this to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

Use MacTeX and TeXworks (which comes with it). MacTeX is a Mac-specific wrapper around TeX Live including some useful extras.